# NullPointer on Multipartfile with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, file, spring-mvc, file-upload, controller

It seems my case is simple, so I'm guessing the problem is stupid.  Nonetheless...I don't see it.

I'm trying to accept the upload of a collection of files and have been looking at this article as a guide:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multiple-file-upload-example/

Here's the form upload client side:

```
<form:form method="post" action="save.html" modelAttribute="uploadArtifact" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="controls" id="artifacts">                               
        <input type="file" id="uploader" class="multi"/>        
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Here's the Model/Bean code:

```
public class ArtifactModel {

private List<MultipartFile> artifacts;

public List<MultipartFile> getArtifacts() {
    return artifacts;
}

public void setArtifacts(List<MultipartFile> artifacts) {
    this.artifacts = artifacts;
}
}
```

...and the controller code:

```
@Controller
public class ArtifactController {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ArtifactController.class);

    // @Autowired
    // ArtifactService artifactService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUploadDialog", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayForm() {
        return "uploadArtifacts";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void save(
            @ModelAttribute("uploadArtifact") ArtifactModel uploadArtifact,
            Model map) {

        logger.info("Received file upload request with     "+uploadArtifact.getArtifacts().size()+" files");
            List<MultipartFile> files = uploadArtifact.getArtifacts();

        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (null != files && files.size() > 0) {
            for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {
                String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
                fileNames.add(fileName);
                // Handle file content - multipartFile.getInputStream()
                logger.info("Received file with filename: " + fileName);
            }
        }

        map.addAttribute("files", fileNames);
    }

}
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I attempt to call the getter on the ArtifactModel object which should have come from the uploadArtifact @ModelAttribute parameter...

I've looked in the browser debugger and seen that the client is sending the data...

Suggestions?

Comment: Try adding an attribute `name='artifacts[0]'` to your file input element.

Comment: That did it.  Why don't you put that in an Answer so I can give you credit where it's due :)  Thank you sir.

Comment: Great, will do. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing an attribute from your file input element.

Try adding:

```
name='artifacts[0]'
```